# Rblpapi overrides setting is unused argument in bds

Tags: r, bloomberg, blpapi, rblpapi

I am trying to use the Rblpapi package, and am able to pull data and connect to the api easily.  However when using overrides I encounter this error everytime.

```
overrd <- c("START_DT" = "20150101", "END_DT" = "20160101")

bds("CPI YOY Index", "ECO_RELEASE_DT_LIST", overrides = overrd)
```

> Error in bds("CPI YOY Index", "ECO_RELEASE_DT_LIST", overrides = overrd) :
>
> unused argument (overrides = overrd)

Has anyone encountered this error?  Do you know what the fix is?

Answer (score 2):

FWIW: When I pasted your code into my R terminal, it worked:

```
> overrd <- c("START_DT"="20150101", "END_DT"="20160101")

bds("CPI YOY Index","ECO_RELEASE_DT_LIST", overrides = overrd)
> >    Ecostats Release Date
1               20150116
2               20150226
3               20150324
4               20150417
5               20150522
6               20150618
7               20150717
8               20150819
9               20150916
10              20151015
11              20151117
12              20151215
```